# Zeta Regularization and Products of Primes

Tags: zeta-functions

How can one prove that:

$2 * 3 * 5 * 7 \ldots = \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} p_i = 4\pi^2$

using zeta regularization?

The sum diverges like the Ramanujan/Euler product but it can be associated to a value on the zeta curve...

Comment: [Casimir Effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_effect) is an application of Zeta Function regularization.

Answer (score 3):

A proof can be found in this [article](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00220-007-0350-z) or this [preprint](http://cds.cern.ch/record/630829).